# Close Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Cannot work out what I am doing wrong here. I want the autocomplete div to close if there is nothing in search field or when any area of the site is clicked, similar to an onblur. Instead the div stays present. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".search").keyup(function() 
{
var searchbox = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'searchword='+ searchbox;

if(searchbox=='')
{
}
else
{

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "search.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{

$("#display").html(html).show();


    }

});
}return false;    

});
});
```

"Display" is my autocomplete div.

Comment: Why don't try Jquery autocomplete  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete????

Comment: try  alert(html); ,get any result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this --

> [see demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/JqBRz/1/)

```
var handler = function(event){    // to hide "#display" on elsewhere click
if($(event.target).not("#display *") || $(".search").val().length != 0) return;    
    $("#display").hide();
}

$(document).on("click", handler);
```

Above handler with hide `display` div when cliked on elsewhere. If clicked inside `display` it will not hide.

And

```
$(".search").keyup(function(){
     var searchbox = $(this).val();
     if(searchbox.length === 0)  // if field is blank hide div again.
           $("#result").hide();
....  // remaining code ----
```